# Overwriting hard drive with Gnome Disks

Tags: linux, ubuntu, gnome

I want to install Ubuntu 20.04 LTS on my machine (I currently am running Fedora 33) but don't have any USB drives to boot from at the moment. I've seen it's possible to "Restore from Disk Image" in `gnome-disk-utility`, and was wondering if it is advisable to restore from a fresh ISO. Would this not be possible and/or backfire due to it not actually being a system snapshot, or would be perfectly fine?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is possible, but it wouldn't give you a fully installed Ubuntu system, if that's what you're expecting.

The Ubuntu ISO image contains a "Live" or "Installer" system preconfigured for that specific task. Whether you write it to a DVD or a USB stick or an internal hard disk, you'll still get the same "Live" system in any case.

But if you have *two* HDDs, then it should be possible to write the image into one of them, boot from it, then use the installer to get a full Ubuntu installation onto another disk.